# Select data from two locations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I need to take data with Redshift Spectrum on S3.
However, I have two different folders (2018 / 2019) that I need to take. How can I take both in the 'location' part?

For now I have:

```
create external table test_spectrum.full_events_test2
(
    timestamp bigint,
    device struct<locale:struct<country:varchar, language:varchar>, platform:struct<name:varchar>>,
)
row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties('ignore.malformed.json'='true', 'paths'='event_type', 'serialization.format'='1')
stored as
inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location 's3://myfolder/2019/'  -- But I want also 's3://myfolder/2018/'
```

But, I want also 's3://myfolder/2018/'

How can I do ?

Comment: Use `location 's3://myfolder/` -- it will include any folders under `myfolder`.

Comment: I know, but there are some files in /myfolder/ that I need to ignore. So, I cannot do that

Comment: rearrange your s3 data so that you have a folder where all subfolders contain similar data that can make up a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish Amazon Redshift Spectrum to scan multiple folders, they must have a common prefix.

It is not possible to specify multiple, separate folders as the location.

Therefore, you should move those folders under a common folder, with no other files in that common folder.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear that there is no way to do in an other way than having a common folder for all files :)